# "Semantic"s relation to "Pedantic"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, semantics

When pointing out to my friends one day that I should have used a different word in a previous conversation, I mentioned that I was being **pedantic**. They, ironically, corrected me saying I was being **semantic**. When I pointed out that their distinction was being pedantic, they again disagreed, saying that was semantic. Though I looked up both definitions and that they seem to have a lot of overlap, `pedantic` seems to be the adjective to use for people though is far more general. Which one is more correct in these situations, or are they both correct? If they are both correct, which one is more "proper?"

Comment: I think you really miss the point there. It's not about correctness, it's about [something else](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+leg).

Comment: This is General Reference. Look the words up in a dictionary and *pay attention* - the definitions are totally different, as are the semantic and grammatical contexts in which they can be used.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question. You can't refer somebody to a dictionary for answers to questions about meaning and pragmatics; they just list usages. If there are a lot, it's easy to get confused.

Comment: The words have completely different meanings, but that's just semantics.

Comment: @kojiro: Apparently they are sometimes used interchangeably by people who should know better, but that's just pedantics.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry to be an anal, but "pedantics" isn't a word.

Comment: @JasonC You could say you're being pedantic.

Comment: @JasonC But is the alternative noun form "pedantry" any better than "pedantics"?

Comment: @AJMansfield "Pedantry" isn't alternative, it's correct.

Comment: Guys, I don't mean to be semantical, but "anal" isn't a noun.

Comment: @Jason: I admit it's not a well-known word *as yet* - but that's just because it's a relatively new coinage of my own, etymologically unconnected to *semantic = pertaining to meaning*. It's based on *[ped](http://membean.com/wrotds/ped-foot) = foot*, and the fact that ballet dancers pirouette on the tip of the foot. So you could in principle get several of them dancing *on one single small point*. Plus ***antics***, obviously. I just figured us Brits need a "secular" alternative to [angels dancing on the head of a pin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/angels_dancing_on_the_head_of_a_pin). :)

Comment: Whether you call it pedantry or semantics is up to you but your example of "irony" isn't.

Comment: This question has no business being closed as general reference. Really, folks, did you actually read the question, or did you just knee-jerk react to the title?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the face of it, the answer to the question in the title cannot be anything other than "mu": these two words are almost completely orthogonal. But given your explanation, I can see where you're coming from.

I would say your friends are wrong, by virtue of the fact that "being" and "semantic" don't go together in my mind. An *argument* can be semantic; a person can't. ([nGram that agrees with me](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being+semantic%2C+being+pedantic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeing%20semantic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeing%20pedantic%3B%2Cc0))

That said, Ronan Murphy is correct in that semantic nitpicking is a specific type of pedantry. You can be pedantic about a lot of things, but when you're pedantic about the meanings of words, then you're engaging in semantic pedantry.

Note that pedantry isn't really the same thing as nitpicking. As a button I own says, "I'm not anal, I'm a pedant. There's a difference. Let me explain...". :)

Comment: "Mu"? What's that?

Comment: +1 for having the right attitude! (Where can I get one of those buttons? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there's usually a button-seller at geeky conventions. My favorites include "'Not a morning person' doesn't even begin to cover it" and "Not born to multitask. Will all tasks please line up in order?"

Comment: @Jim: "mu" is the answer to a question that asks the wrong thing, like the proverbial "Have you stopped beating your wife yet?" It's the answer that simultaneously means all of *yes*, *no*, *black*, *white*, *wicker chair*, and *poinsettia*.

Comment: @Jim: It's not a usage I'm familiar with, but [here it is in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)) citing the same archetypal example as Martha. My version is [None of the Above](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/none+of+the+above), which I intend using as the name for a new political party I'm founding. All preliminary market research suggests we will win the next election in the UK by a landslide.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks. Only an Eastern Philosophy would suggest you can un-ask a question. In Western Science, I might call it QM. But "None of the Above" works for me.

Comment: In Western Philosophy, we say "You're asking the wrong question". "Mu" just saves time and typing.

Comment: @Jim: For certain questions, such as *"How many years old is the Christian God?"*, another useful one might be [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) ("Not a Number"). Being something of a "Western civilisation" [logical positivist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logical+positivism) myself, I don't have a lot of time for the idea that "Eastern Philosophy" *koans* & such contribute much to our understanding of nature/reality and our place within it, but that's just a personal perspective.

Comment: @Jim Hofstadter delves more deeply into the concept of mu in _Gödel, Escher, Bach._  If you are interested, I think you'd enjoy it.

Comment: I think "mu" works for "Your question hinges on so many premises and unspoken assumptions that I don't hold, I can't answer it in a way that will communicate what I actually think accurately"

Comment: @Tyler James Young: Thanks for the tip. I might like it.

Answer (score 7):

They are two completely separate concepts.

[Pedantic](http://i.word.com/idictionary/pedantic) means being overly scrupulous in your assessment.  In other words, sticking too closely to strict definitions at the cost of the overall meaning.

[Semantic](http://m.dictionary.com/definition/semantic) means pertaining to meaning in language.

They are not interchangeable, though they are frequently used that way.

The expression *that's just semantics* really means you are not arguing the premise, just what to call it.  (Note that this argument is actually backwards since semantics implies the meaning of the words rather than the choice of words.)

The expression *you are being pedantic* means that you are nitpicking over unimportant details in the argument.  In other words, if you are discussing George Washington's horsemanship:  trying to discredit your opponents point of view because his horse was white not brown.  That would be pedantic.

It is absolutely possible to have pedantic semantic argument, but it doesn't make them equivalent.

And, before it gets said in comments my post is both pedantic and semantic!

Comment: I have *never in my life* heard anyone say *"You are [just] being semantic."* To me, it's just meaningless gobbledegook, and I don't think it would be unduly pedantic of me to point this out.

Comment: No, _semantic_ means pertaining to **meaning**. [Semantics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Semantics.pdf) is one of the core disciplines of linguistics.  All linguistics, not just semantics, "pertains to language".

Comment: @fumblefingers It would be pedantic since I never used that phrase in my post.

Comment: @JohnLawler that was a phone based error. Sometimes I lose track of what I've typed on the small screen. I've edited it to be correct.

Comment: Thanks. I still think I'm gonna hafta answer this one, though.

Comment: @JohnLawler as always I welcome your superior font of knowledge.

Comment: Hmm. *"They are not interchangeable, though they **are frequently used that way**."* In *my* version of English, saying words are frequently used interchangeably means that since people often say *"You're just being **pedantic**"*, they should often replace that word with the alternative. Which in my experience simply isn't the case. Making that substitution would be both grammatically and semantically incorrect, and would rarely/never occur with competent/careful speakers.

Comment: @DavidM: Gimme a break, please. FF: I've heard and seen it used in that sense, and even experienced that expression. Like I say, I gotta answer this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I *did* say they were not interchangeable. I'm not responsible for people using it incorrectly. And, unfortunately, many of my American brethren say this.

Comment: @JohnLawler I actually meant that sincerely. I know the internet carries an inherent sense of sarcasm.  But, I've learned a considerable amount from your posts.

Comment: @John: Yes - the usage sounds really ignorant to me, but I just checked Google Books and found [a *US senator* and an *astronomer*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+are+being+semantic%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) doing it. Whatever next? *"You are just being grammar"*?

Comment: Oh @FumbleFingers you are *just being grammar!*. I like it!  Gonna start using it! ;-)

Comment: @David: If we're gonna fight it out over the "validity/acceptability" of specific usages, [baggsy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bagsy) I'm the freedom fighter defending mine and Humpty-Dumpty's right to use words any which way we like, and *you* can be the Grammar Nazi! :)

Comment: @Fumblefingers we say dibs over here!  Never heard baggsy. I like it.  I'm not quite the grammarian you'd have me be. I'm just a bit overly concrete in my pedantry at times.  How's that for a redundancy!?!

Comment: @Fumblefingers Also, Godwin's Law of Grammar, perhaps?  Comparing one's grammatical statements to that a Nazi might make?  New coinage?

Comment: @David: I know it's originally/primarily American, but we also use ***dibs***. Grammatically it's not quite "interchangeable" though - I'd have had to use it in a phrase such as ***I claim first dibs that...*** to directly substitute for the full meaning and grammatical affordances of our ***bagsy***.

Comment: ...I was introduced to the term [Grammar Nazi](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/grammar-nazi) by my daughter years ago (by being labelled as one! :) It's certainly a bit more "expressive" than [Grammar Police](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Grammar+Police), but according to that Urban Dictionary link, *Grammar Police are NOT in affiliation with Grammar Nazis.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, they're not affiliated. Direct competitors for all of your grammar pedantry needs …

Comment: So by the time I get around to answering it, it's offtopic. OK. The Gods Have Spoken.

Comment: @JohnLawler I assume your answer was going to be something along the lines of my example of semantic argument was backwards.  I edited later and acknowledged that.

Answer (score 4):

Your friend was attempting to be witty, but I guess they didn't quite get their point across there.

Compare with the following hypothetical conversation...

**Customer:** Hi, I ordered a rugby ball from your website, but you sent me a soccer ball.

**Shop-keeper:** Sounds like a clerical error.

**Customer:** I think you mean spherical error.

Hint - you were being both pedantic and semantic, although it's true that "being semantic" isn't common usage.

Answer (score 4):

The dictionary definitions actually give a decent hint (from Merriam-Webster online):

> Semantic - adj. of or relating to the meanings of words and phrases
>
> Pedantic - adj. of, relating to, or being a pedant
>
> Pedant - n. 1. one who makes a show of knowledge, 2. one who is unimaginative or who unduly emphasizes minutiae in the presentation or use of knowledge, 3. a formalist or precisionist in teaching

Those definitions don't leave much up for debate; the words are very different. From them, it is fairly easy to see the differences. In particular:

- "Semantic" would not be used to describe a person, as it is generally nonsense to say that a person is "of or relating to the meanings of words and phrases" (this is the primary reason why your friends are incorrect). An idea/thing could be "semantic".
- "Semantic" is specific to words and phrases. "Pedantic" covers everything. You can be pedantic about issues that aren't semantic.

So you can be pedantic, or your argument can be semantic, or you can be pedantic about semantic things, or pedantic about semantics. You'd never really be semantic. (Note, by the way, that the noun ["semantics"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semantics) is related to the adjective "semantic" but, of course, is not the "plural" of it; there is no noun "semantic".)

Your friends *could* have said something more along the lines of "You are concentrating too much on semantics", or "You are getting caught up with semantic details", but definitely not "You are being semantic".

Answer (score 0):

Semantic is specifically related to words and their use, so you could be semantic about using "a different word in a previous conversation". You could also be pedantic about this, but because pedantic is a more general term, you could be pedantic about how you like your shelves organised, but you wouldn't be semantic about it.

Comment: ...and what Reg said. :)

Answer (score 0):

They're different words. Semantics refers to the meaning of words: for example, I could talk about the word "ball" in terms of its semantics; in that case, I would say that it means a spherical object, typically able to be thrown, and can sometimes be bounced. Pedantry (adjective pedantic) is when someone is being nit-picky, criticising apparently minor errors or flaws in something.

Lately, people seem to use the phrase "That's just a matter of semantics" to imply that someone is being pedantic. At the moment, this is a misuse of the word. The idea behind the phrase is to suggest that the other person is getting too deeply involved in the meaning of the words, where the distinction doesn't really matter. The phrase suggests someone is being pedantic. Over time that's probably become shortened to "semantics", and I imagine this is why your friends equate the two. But right now, they're definitely different words. That may well change.